# Call many variables in a for loop with dplyr/ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyeval

Sometimes when performing exploratory analysis or producing reports we want to plot univariate distributions for many variables. I could do this faceting the plot after some tidy trick, but there's ordered factors and I want to keep them ordered on the plots.

So, to accomplish it in a more efficient way, I built a simple `dplyr`/`ggplot` based function. I made this example below using the Arthritis dataset of `vcd` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data(Arthritis, package = "vcd")

head(Arthritis)

plotUniCat <- function(df, x) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!x)) %>%
    count(!!x) %>%
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y=prop, x=!!x)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
}

plotUniCat(Arthritis, Improved)
```

I can plot a formatted graph in a very short way, which is cool, but with just one variable.

I tried to call more than one variable with a for loop, but it's not working. The code runs, but nothing happens.

```
variables <- c("Improved", "Sex", "Treatment")

for (i in variables) {
  plotUniCat(Arthritis, noquote(i))
}
```

I searched about this, but it's still not clear for me. Does someone know what I am doing wrong or how to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There might be a couple of things going on.  Put a print around the plot call: print(plotUniCat(Arthritis, noquote(i)) )

Comment: Using `print()` statement is part of the solution here @HarlanNelson. It was the simplest way, but only if I mix with `rlang::sym()` solution presented by the other guys either. If I do not change `quo()` for `sym()` returns a "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" error. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `enquo` in the function to `sym`, to convert the variable string to a symbol.  That is,

```
plotUniCat <- function(df, x) {
  x <- sym(x)
  df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!x)) %>%
    count(!!x) %>%
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y=prop, x=!!x)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
}
```

or, more concisely,

```
plotUniCat <- function(df, x) {
  x <- sym(x)
  df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!x)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(!!x))) +
    geom_histogram(stat = "count")
}
```

and then

```
out <- lapply(variables, function(i) plotUniCat(Arthritis,i))
```

Finally, use `grid.arrange` to display the plots. E.g.

```
library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(out, ncol = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very similar to the Tung's answer. Both works for what I want. But I mark yours as correct by substitute for loop with `lapply()` instead of the `purrr::map()` and by `grid.arrange()` inclusion, wich organizes plot output. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `rlang::sym` to convert strings to symbols instead of `enquo`. I replace `for` loop with `purrr::map` to loop through the `variables`

```r
library(tidyverse)

data(Arthritis, package = "vcd")

head(Arthritis)
#>   ID Treatment  Sex Age Improved
#> 1 57   Treated Male  27     Some
#> 2 46   Treated Male  29     None
#> 3 77   Treated Male  30     None
#> 4 17   Treated Male  32   Marked
#> 5 36   Treated Male  46   Marked
#> 6 23   Treated Male  58   Marked

plotUniCat2 <- function(df, x) {
  x <- rlang::sym(x)
  df %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!x)) %>%
    count(!!x) %>%
    mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y=prop, x=!!x)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
}

variables <- c("Improved", "Sex", "Treatment")

variables %>% purrr::map(., ~ plotUniCat2(Arthritis, .x))
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```r
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

```r
#> 
#> [[3]]
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks Tung! It was very useful, but i prefered the lapply() solution made by Weihuang.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the OP would like to use the `plotUniCat` for both quoted and unquoted variable name. If we change the function, it would not work for `plotUniCat(Arthritis, Improved)`.

Therefore, instead of change the function, we can also change the way how we call the function `plotUniCat` into:

```
for (i in variables) {
    plotUniCat(Arthritis, !!rlang::sym(i))
}
```

However, the plots are generated but not returned by `for`. We can use `print` or `lapply` to force the display or collect the generated plots:

```
lapply(variables, function(i) plotUniCat(Arthritis, !!rlang::sym(i)))
```